# Macbook Retina running Ubuntu 13.04 Problem

Tags: 13.04, macbook, macbook-pro

I install Ubuntu 13.04 using Refind. It works ok, but when I close the notebook, it shuts down. Does anybody have any solution to this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set what happens when you "close the lid". To do that follow the following steps:

1. Open `System Settings` located on the left.

[image]

 2. A new Window just opened. Click on the `Power Settings` located under Hardware.

[image]

 3. In the `Power Settings` you can choose what happens when you close the lid or when power is critical low etc. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I had done this before. I've been using Linux for almost 2 years. This is probably a problem that needs a driver to be solved. Does anybody here had the same problem with the macbook retina?